# NG child component NOT calling service

Tags: angular, angular-services

I have 2 components: NowRunningComponent and MovieDetailComponent. On click event in NowRunningComponent I am setting Input() selectedMovie in MovieDetailComponent. In MovieDetailComponent I am listening to ngOnChanges and I am calling the YT service on property changes. I have injected YT service in MovieDetailComponent. However facing an error from NowRunningComponent in HTML.

```
NowRunningComponent.html:8 ERROR TypeError: this.ytService.getYTvideos is not a function
    at MovieDetailComponent.push../src/app/movie-detail/movie-detail.component.ts.MovieDetailComponent.ngOnChanges (movie-detail.component.ts:26)
    at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline (core.js:20661)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (core.js:21929)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (core.js:21891)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (core.js:22525)
    at debugCheckDirectivesFn (core.js:22485)
```

NowRunningComponent.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-now-running',
  templateUrl: './now-running.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./now-running.component.css']
})
export class NowRunningComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private nowrunningService: NowRunningServiceService) { }
  movies: Array<Movie>=[];
selectedMovie: Movie;
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("MOvies length"+ this.movies);
    this.nowrunningService.getNowRunningMovies().subscribe((data:any) => {
      this.movies= data.results;

    });

  }

  posterClick(movie: Movie) {
    this.selectedMovie=movie;
    console.log(this.selectedMovie.original_title + " Selected.")
    console.log(this.selectedMovie.title + " Selected.")
  }
}
```

NowRunning Component HTML:

```
...
<app-movie-detail [selectedMovie] = "selectedMovie"></app-movie-detail>
...
```

MovieDetailComponent.ts

```
export class MovieDetailComponent implements OnInit,OnChanges {

  @Input()
  selectedMovie:Movie;
  constructor(private ytService: YoutubeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('movie detail init');
  }
  videos:Array<any>=[];
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {

    console.log('movie changed');
    console.log(`Changes: ${JSON.stringify(changes)})`);
     if(this.selectedMovie.title!= null)
      {
        this.ytService.getYTvideos(this.selectedMovie.title).subscribe((data:any) => {
          this.videos= data.items;

        });
      }
  }

}
```

YouTubeService.ts

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class YoutubeService {

  search_url = "/yt-vid/";
  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getYTvideos (title) {
    return this.http.get(globals.api_base_href+this.search_url+title);
  }
}
```

The error is generated from the NowRuningComponent HTML. Could you share your thoughts here? Should I do EventEmitter?

Answer (score 0):

First things first,

```
  getYTvideos (title) {
```

that space between `getYTvideos` and `(title)` looks like a syntax error. At least it acts like one when I try to declare a function this way.

(Second, if that's not it, I'd convert `getYTvideos` to an arrow function).

Comment: thanks for the answer. it resolved itself after killing ng serve and running again.